# Google graph show extra label with numeric value

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to add custom label as target achieved with numeric value, which is just a value but not the calculation of graph bar/height.

I am not getting how to get the similar result as showed in screen shot,

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xv867tur/

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation' });
  
  data.addRows([
    ['Foo', 53, 'Foo text'],
    ['Bar', 71, 'Bar text'],
    ['Baz', 36, 'Baz text'],
    ['Cad', 42, 'Cad text'],
    ['Qud', 87, 'Qud text'],
    ['Pif', 64, 'Pif text']
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, 1, 2]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(view, {
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    series: {
      0: {
        type: 'bars'
      },
      1: {
        type: 'line',
        color: 'grey',
        lineWidth: 0,
        pointSize: 0,
        visibleInLegend: false
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      maxValue: 100
    }
  });
}
```

**Expected result :**

[image]

Comment: Can you post what's your actual result please ?

Comment: @SullivanTobias https://i.stack.imgur.com/84zyF.png here i posted already in question too.